# what are the maps in this exact sequence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the complex number and $D$ a divisor with simple normal crossings. Denote by $U$ the complement of $D$ in $X$. Then one has a long exact sequence in singular cohomology
$$
\cdots \to H^{n-1}(D) \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} H^n_c(U) \stackrel{\beta}{\longrightarrow} H^n(X) \stackrel{\gamma}{\longrightarrow} H^j(D) \to \cdots 
$$

Here the map $\gamma$ is the pull-back of the inclusion $D \hookrightarrow X$ (that is, given by restriction).

What are the other maps? I guess residues along $D$ are going to play some role here, but I don't understand exactly how.

Comment: Why do you take a normal crossings divisor? This holds for any closed subvariety $D$ of $X$.

Comment: Because I would like to relate the maps to the Poincaré residues

Comment: If $D$ is a smooth divisor, $\alpha $ corresponds through Poincar\'e duality to ${}^t\alpha :H^p(U)\rightarrow H^{p-1}(D)$, with $p:=2\dim(X)-n$, which is indeed given by Poincar\'e residue.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens when $D$ is not smooth? This is the case I'm interested in